# Retrieve Related Models using Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have 3 tables: Users, Projects, Items and Friends. I want to get all the items for a project and list each item with related friends. Am I missing something in my model? Ultimately I want to get all the friends which are related to the items.

```
// CONTROLLER

public function show($id)
{
    $uid = Auth::user()->id;

    $projects = Project::find($id)->with('item.friend')->get();

    return View::make('projects.show', compact('projects'));
}

//VIEW

@foreach ($projects as $project)
    @foreach ($project->friend as $friend)

        <li>

            <a href="#" class='itemLink' >{{$friend->email}}</a>

            <a href="#" class='itemLink' >{{$projects->item->name}}</a>

        </li>
    @endforeach
@endforeach

// MODELS

class User extends Eloquent {

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Project');
    }

    public function item()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Item');
    }

        public function friend()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Friend');
    }



class Project extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function item()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Item');
    }

        public function friend()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Friend');
    }

class Item extends Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();


    public function friend()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Friend');
    }

class Friend extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What Laravel says?

Comment: I am getting: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a loop.  I recommend that when setting up a many to many relationship, make sure your method is plural.  It makes a lot more sense when trying to read the code.  You'd then send up with `@foreach $project->items as $item` or `$item->friends as $friend`.

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)
    @foreach ($project->item as $item)
        @foreach($item->friend as $friend)

        <li>

            <a href="#" class='itemLink' >{{$friend->email}}</a>

            <a href="#" class='itemLink' >{{$item->name}}</a>

        </li>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Your models seems OK at first look. I think since you are pulling `item.friend` relationship, this line

```
@foreach ($project->friend as $friend)
```

should be,

```
@foreach ($project->item->friend as $friend)
```

Comment: When I added that I get this: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$friend

Comment: Sorry, I missed it first time. But as far as I understand You are eager loading it wrong. Syntax I typically use for similar purposes is,

`Project:with('item.friend')->get()` Which will return the all the projects with `item.friend` eager loaded. 

I will edit the answer if the solution works for you.